# Cypress: How to retry entire test suite?

Tags: cypress, test-suite

**Goal**
Be able to perform multiple retries of an entire test suite until all tests succeed.

Instead of configuring retries allowed for every test within a test suite, as defined by [Configure Test Retries: Global Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Global-Configuration)

**How to provide test suite retries?**

If any test fails within a test suite, then start over and retry the entire test suite again until all tests within a test suite succeed or stop when the entire test suite retry attempts exceed the requested retry attempts.

In the following code, configures retry attempts applicable for every test within a test suite.

The desired goal for this test suite, **test `'TEST counter'`** is expected to fail until incrementing `_counter` equals `_runModeRetries` and only then is it expected to succeed. Repeat the entire test suite means re-run every test prior to **test `'TEST counter'`** until it succeeds.

However, what happens is that only **test `'TEST counter'`** is retried `_runModeRetries` times, and `_counter` is not incremented because **test `'TEST increment'`** is called only once.

**Why do I want this?**

I have test suites that have a series of tests the required to run in sequence, and if a test fails, then retries require restarting the sequence. For example, `_counter` can only be incremented if **test `'TEST increment'`** is called again with a full test suite retry.

**How can I do test suite retries?**

```js
  let _counter = 0;
  const _runModeRetries = 3;

  context(
    'CONTEXT Cypress Retries',
    {
      retries: {
        runMode: _runModeRetries,
        openMode: 0
      }
    },
    () => {
      it('TEST increment', () => {
        _counter++;
        expect(_counter).to.be.a('number').gt(0);
      });

      it('TEST true', () => {
        expect(true).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.true;
      });

      it('TEST false', () => {
        expect(false).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.false;
      });

      it('TEST counter', () => {
        if (_counter < _runModeRetries) {
          assert.fail();
        } else {
          assert.isTrue(true);
        }
      });
    }
  );
```

Comment: Surely there is a better way to decouple your tests dependency. Things could get messy and hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

This is really hacky, I'm but posting it in case you can improve on it

- run the suite `_runModeRetries`  times
- add a `skip` variable to control if tests run
- make all tests `function()` so that `this.skip()` can be called
- add an `after()` within the suite to set `skip` true after first pass
- add an onFail handler to reset `skip` when a fail occurs

```js
let _counter = 0;
const _runModeRetries = 3;
let skip = false

Cypress.on('fail', (error, test) => {
  skip = false
  throw error  // behave as normal
})

Cypress._.times(_runModeRetries, () => {

  context('CONTEXT', {retries: {runMode: _runModeRetries}}, () => {
      it('TEST increment', function() {
        if (skip) this.skip()
        _counter++;
        expect(_counter).to.be.a('number').gt(0);
      });
      it('TEST true', function() {
        if (skip) this.skip()
        expect(true).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.true;
      });
      it('TEST false', function() {
        if (skip) this.skip()
        expect(false).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.false;
      });
      it('TEST counter', function() {
        if (skip) this.skip()
        assert.isTrue(_counter < _runModeRetries ? false :true);
      });
    }
  );
  after(() => skip = true)  // any fail, this does not run 
})
```

There may be some improvements available by adjusting the suite inside the onFail (suite = test.parent) and avoiding adding the changes to individual tests.

---

A cleaner way is to use the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api) which would allow you to run the test suite, examine the results and run again if there's any fail. Sort of manual-retry.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your reply!